# How to draw square in Turtle module without filling color?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to draw a square in turtle without any thing filled in it. I would manually draw it with a loop, but I am trying to write a program where if the square is touched, something would happen. If I drew it with a loop, even if I touch the border, it would not work, because the actual turtle isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by dedicating one turtle as the button.  We need to change its shape, size and fill color and assign it a button event handler:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def thanks(x, y):
    marker.write("Thank you!", align='center', font=('Arial', 24, 'bold'))

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.penup()
marker.sety(-200)

button = Turtle()
button.shape('square')
button.fillcolor('white')
button.shapesize(3)
button.onclick(thanks)

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Click on the square in the middle of the screen and it will thank you for doing so.

> I am trying to draw a square in turtle without any thing filled in it.

The above solution does use a *filled* turtle, it just happens to be white fill.  We can't draw within the square that is this button.  If that's the need, then we can draw the square with a loop, but move our `onclick()` from the turtle to the screen.  We'll need to make the `onclick()` itself determine if it's in the right place:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BUTTON_POSITION = (100, 100)
BUTTON_SIZE = 60

def thanks(x, y):
    bx, by = BUTTON_POSITION

    if bx < x < bx + BUTTON_SIZE and by < y < by + BUTTON_SIZE:
        turtle.write("Thank you!", align='center', font=('Arial', 24, 'bold'))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

# draw the button
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(BUTTON_POSITION)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(BUTTON_SIZE)
    turtle.left(90)

# decorate our button a bit
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(BUTTON_SIZE/2)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(BUTTON_SIZE/2)
turtle.dot()

# position turtle for writing later
turtle.goto(0, -200)

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(thanks)
screen.mainloop()
```